# Sharepoint 2010 OOTB Workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a SharePoint list with the fields;

Name | Email | Age |

I need to create a workflow to send a email using the Email field as a destination, but i cant use SharePoint designer and that email must have some degree of customization  can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

If you can NOT use SharePoint Designer, I'm afraid customising the email is going to be a painful process. 
I take it your company has some sort of policy against the use of SPD... In such case, you're really only left with the deployed workflows in your farm and whatever customisation they allow. By virtue of the fact that you're asking this question, you've already discovered that the out of the box workflows do not allow you to do what you need. That leaves you with building and deploying a custom, reusable workflow with Visual Studio.  Here's the Microsoft guide on doing that. 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163199.aspx